Help Identifying Burnt Audio Amplifier IC on Seasonal Visions International Holiday Mickey (Model 23SV24033)
I’m working on repairing a 4-foot tall animated “Holiday Mickey” decoration from Seasonal Visions International (Model: 23SV24033), but I’ve encountered an issue with the sound component. There’s a burnt audio amplifier IC located near the speaker connector, and unfortunately, I can only see partial markings on it due to the damage.
Here’s what I’ve identified so far:
•   Partially visible markings on the IC: “1B,” “264,” and “HBC01A” are all I can make out.
•   Nearby components include a chip with the number TRSF 16127A and another labeled TC118AH.

I’ve reached out to Seasonal Visions International, but they haven’t responded, and I haven’t found any schematic or replacement info online. Any guidance on identifying this amplifier IC or suggestions for compatible substitutes would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance
